# Canon 60D live view on screen while connected to tv?

Tags: canon, live-view

Is it possible to see live view on a Canon 60D while recording, and at the same time get connected to the tv with the AV cable? Because the tv is in the other ROom, so i need to se whats happening while im recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to see live view on a Canon 60D while recording, and at the same time get connected to the tv with the AV cable?

**No.** When you connect the HDMI or AV cable to the camera, the display is routed to that output instead of the camera's screen.

Your best bet might be to use small external monitor (battery powered 7" HDMI monitors meant for use with DSLR's and video cameras are pretty cheap these days) and a HDMI splitter. That would let you monitor the video while you're recording and still display it on a screen in the other room.